# How to add my custom error on "/api" documentation api-platform

Tags: symfony, error-handling, api-platform.com

I'm developing an application with Symfony 4 and Api-Platform.

I created a custom error `xxxException`, based on [these docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/). I used it on post operation and it works fine.

Now I want to expose my error on API documentation when I access to `some-url/api`.

How to do it, so it appears like the following image?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying render an example of the error for your docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `SwaggerDecorator` as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification).

Then in your `App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator` class in your `normalize` method you can change the documentation like this (here is an example for adding documentation and responses to a custom login operation):

```php
public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
{
    $documentation = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

    $documentation['paths']['/login'] = [ // "/login" is the path of the operation
        'post' => [ // "post" is the http request method
            'responses' => [
                '200' => [ // 200 is the http response code
                    'description' => 'Successful log in.',
                ],
                '401' => [ // 401 another http response code
                    'description' => 'Bad credentials.',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $documentation;
}
```

Note: The documentation variable is just an array or an object implementing `ArrayAccess` you can dump it and edit as you wish.

Comment: thanks for repling, that seems great an helpfull.
another question: can i have two 400 erros on responses array???

Comment: I think you can't. I didn't test this but this is an array and arrays can't have items with same keys.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Simeons answer, I'd like to add that his example overide all keys for his '/login' example, because he override the full array for that post operation.

If you only want to override or add documentation for a specific http status code, then you can do it like this

```
public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        // Document custom errors that we get from exceptions registered in config/packages/api_platform.yaml
        $docs['paths']['/api/books']['post']['responses']['409'] = ['description' => 'The book is no longer available'];

        return $docs;
    }
```

You can add configure your http status codes by mapping your custom exceptions to a code in config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    exception_to_status:
        # The 4 following handlers are registered by default, keep those lines to prevent unexpected side effects
        Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface: 400 # Use a raw status code (recommended)
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: 'HTTP_BAD_REQUEST' # Or a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`'s constant
        ApiPlatform\Core\Exception\FilterValidationException: 400
        Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException: 409

        # Custom mapping
        App\Exception\SpaceUnavailableException: 409
```

Comment: Yes of corse, just i want to know http error code that i can override for my custom errors if you can help me

Comment: @walidtlili I added info on how to map your custom exceptions to status codes